# Does performing bardic music while in a threatened square provoke an attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, bard

Using a bardic music ability is a standard action, if the bard performs his bardic music while in a threatened square does he provoke an attack of opportunity as if casting a spell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Starting a [spell-like](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#spell-like-abilities) bardic music effect provokes attacks of opportunity

The *Player's Handbook* has a notation after each [bardic music](http://dndsrd.net/bard.html#bardic-music) effect that specifies whether a bardic music effect is a [spell-like ability](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#spell-like-abilities) (Sp) or a [supernatural ability](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#supernatural-abilities) (Su). These special abilities aren't called out as being different from typical spell-like or supernatural abilities *except* in that a bardic music effect must "be activated by reciting poetry, chanting, singing lyrical songs, singing melodies…, whistling, playing an instrument, or playing an instrument in combination with some spoken performance" (29).

So, while some typical bardic music effects are supernatural abilities that *don't* provoke attacks of opportunity—like countersong and inspire courage, competence, greatness, and heroics—, other bardic music effects—like *fascinate*, *suggestion*, *song of freedom*, and *mass suggestion*—are spell-like abilities, and a bard that starts these, like a typical creatures that employs a spell-like ability, provokes attacks of opportunity from foes that can make such attacks of opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Bardic performances that are marked (Sp) for spell-like ability provoke; see [HeyICanChan’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/106890/4563)

But as for bardic performances in general, or the non-spell-like ones specifically, no, they do not.

The word “provoke” and the phrase “attack of opportunity” do not appear anywhere in the [SRD description of the bard class](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm), bardic performance included.

The word “bard” does not appear in the SRD descriptions of [attacks of opportunity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/attacksOfOpportunity.htm) or [actions in combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm).

Thus neither side explicitly lists the other as a concern, so we fall back on the [general rule for supernatural abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities) like bardic performance:

> supernatural abilities do not provoke attacks of opportunity

You *could maybe* make an argument that it does based on the “use skill that takes 1 action” entry in Table: Standard Actions in the actions in combat section, which says that such skill usage “usually” provokes an attack of opportunity. However, there are two issues with this: the actual Perform skill description makes no note about it provoking attacks of opportunity (and provoking skill usages should be noted in their skill description), and secondly, *bardic performance does not actually involve using the Perform skill*. You need a certain number of ranks in Perform, but you make no Perform check and none of the things described under Perform actually happen. So at best you are arguing that bardic performance implicitly involves the character doing the same motions that they would when using Perform, and then arguing that Perform provokes attacks of opportunity because skills “usually” do. That’s a whole lot of debatable positions that have to all go your way for bardic performances to provoke, but it’s not *entirely* impossible.

Either way, as a DM I would never make bardic performance provoke unless I had warned players about it at the beginning of the game, before any of them chose the bard class, and I *would* warn them if I wanted it to do so. The preponderance of rules says no and I would consider it a houserule for it to start doing so.

Comment: Right. You're not making a skill check even though it requires skill ranks.